# React Chakra UI Button with two text, big and smaller

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

is it possible in Chakra UI, to build a button that has

- text
- a smaller text
  ?

See the image with the output I have to reach:

[image: button I want to compose]

My code so far is this:

import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'

```
import {
  Button,
  DocumentIcon,
  DownloadIcon,
  Menu,
  MenuButton
} from '@custom/mantle-ui'

<Menu> 
  <MenuButton
    aria-label="Single Report with all"
    as={Button}
    colorScheme="gray"
    iconSpacing={0}
    leftIcon={<DocumentIcon />}
    rightIcon={<DownloadIcon />}
    size="sm"
    variant="solidLight"
  >
    Report per asset
  </MenuButton>
  </Menu>
```

Where **Button** is this component:
[Chakra UI Button](https://%20https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/button)

Where **Menu** is this component:
[Chakra UI Menu](https://%20https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/menu)

Where **MenuButton** is this component:
[MenuButton](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menubutton/)

[mantle-ui button menu](https://mantle-ui.seismic.com/#/Navigation/ButtonMenu)

With this code, the visual result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your purpose with `MenuButton` but I am assuming you want to add both texts to the `MenuButton`

```js
  <MenuButton as={Button} rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />} display="block">
    <Text fontSize="xl" fontWeight="black">
      Big text
    </Text>
    <Text fontSize="sm">Sub text</Text>
  </MenuButton>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work:  JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)

**'Text' cannot be used as a JSX component.**

  Its type '{ new (data?: string): Text; prototype: Text; }' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type '{ new (data?: string): Text; prototype: Text; }' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => Component<any, any, any>'

Comment: <MenuButton> is a button with a menu, that has two options, PDF or DOCX, that's why it is a MenuButton.

Comment: If you are using `chakra-ui` menu button it will work. It seems like mantle-ui seems to have a completely different menu button implementation. Could you please confirm as to which menubutton are you using? 

https://mantle-ui.seismic.com/#/Navigation/ButtonMenu vs https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/menu